# URL parameters causing 404 on home page, but nowhere else

Tags: plugins, filters, urls, 404-error

I am writing a plugin that utilizes URL parameters. For some reason, adding one of these parameters to the home page of my website causes a 404 (http://bleaney.ca/?source=asdf). Adding the parameter to any other page, however, doesn't cause a 404 (http://bleaney.ca/work-experience-2/?source=asdf). This 404 issue only manifested itself after I registered the parameter with Wordpress:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_visitor_identifier_query_vars' );
function register_visitor_identifier_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'source';
    return $qvars;
}
```

On the 404 page, the URL parameter is still detected by this code, the page itself just 404s for some reason:

```
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['source'])) {
    echo $wp_query->query_vars['source'];
}
```

Any idea what is causing this and how I can fix it? I think the workaround of just setting the home page to have a longer ULR like the work experience link would work, but I'd rather fix this issue if possible, rather than work around it.

Comment: Where are you adding this filter to?

Comment: Any luck here? I'm having the same issue with 404s on the homepage after modiflying the $wp->query_vars object via the parse_request hook in WP

Comment: I actually found the code that was the issue, so I've modified my own version of wordpress. I still need to figure out the process for submitting a patch though.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. I found that the issue was caused because I had set the front page to display a static page for the front page and another for the posts page. (Set in Reading Settings)

[image]

However, my posts page had been deleted. In this case because we decided not to have a posts page any more. The URL variables were trying to switch the home page view to the posts page that did not exist.

I fixed this by updating my template to use `front-page.php` (rather than a page template) and changed the setting so that the front page displays `Your latest posts`.

[image]

This solution worked for me because I did not need the posts page.